# How can persist multiple levels of children with the last of them with a composite ID with Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've been struggling with this. How can persist this object?

> I'm getting this error: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session.

It is because the client id is because is not yet persisted, I guess. Here you have the code. I've skipped getters and setters for avoid boilerplate.

**Parent**

`@Table(name = "SHOP")
public class ShopEntity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "SHOP_SEQ_GEN")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SHOP_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "SHOP_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Long location;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ClientEntity> clients;
```

}`

**First children
**
`@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class ClientEntity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "CLIENT_SEQ_GEN")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CLIENT_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "CLIENT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

private String clientCode;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
private ShopEntity shop;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ClientItemEntity> items;
```

}`

**Children of previous children**

`@Table(name = "CLIENT_ITEM")
public class ClientItemEntity {

```
@EmbeddedId
private ClientItemEntityId clientItemEntityId;

private String name;

@MapsId("clientId")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "clientId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ClientItemEntity clientItemEntity;
```

}`

**The composite id:**

`public class AntigenTableDonorAntigenEntityId implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3758107709461624214L;

private Long clientId;

private String itemCode;
```

}`

I have all the properties filled except whe clientId because it not yet exists.

I'm doing the following:

`public interface ShopRepositoryJpa extends JpaRepository<ShopEntity, Long> {}`

`shopRepositoryJpa.save(shop);`

When shop object has its client children without ID because they are new an they are not yet persisted.

Thanks